# Adjusting Phantom Points in True Type Font Hints

Tags: truetype

I try to write TrueType font hints for a barcode font.

The purpose of the hints is to make sure, that the font is scaled in such a way, that the barcodes modules width is an integer number of pixels (because everything else will make the barcode unreadable).

This requires me to first compute the module size in pixels (rounding down) and than to adjust all control points in the font to integer multiples of the module size. I also have to adjust the character widths to the new size.

I have prep instructions which modifies the CVT and individual glyph instructions (MIAP [0]) to copy some of these values to some of the points.

While this works with normal points, modifying the 2nd phantom point (the character advance) seems not to work.

Any ideas?